# Why does tomcat work with Facelets?

Tags: java, tomcat

> The Apache Tomcat® software is an open source implementation of the Java Servlet, JavaServer Pages, Java Expression Language and Java WebSocket technologies.

Source: http://tomcat.apache.org/

So it is a implementation of the JavaServer Pages technology, but it does not say that it is a implementation of the Facelets technology. Why does tomcat still work with XHTML-files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facelets are part of JSF framework, and are implemented by JSF library you are using. More info http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijtu.html

Answer (score 0):

Facelets are implemented in code.  This code can either be provided inside the webserver itself (which is what larger webservers like Glassfish do) or brought along with the rest of your code in the deployed WAR files.

You will need to add the necessary configuration for it to work.  The exact details depend on the path chosen.